# Lightning Styling - Component Not Rendering with Default Style

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning, salesforce-classic, style

Just getting my feet wet in lightning.

I am trying to render the following lightning app in Salesforce classic. However the form displayed is returned only in basic HTML (without the default lightning styling).

Is it required that lightning be enabled to render lightning components? I would think not since the lightning components can be rendered on visualforce pages. Do I need to include any additional markup to render correctly?

**appName.app:**

```
<aura:application>
<c:myFirstComponent/>
</aura:application>
```

**myfirstComponent.cmp:**

```
<aura:component implements="force:appHostable">

    <div class="row">
        <h2 class="header">Basic Input Text</h2>
        <lightning:input name="input1" label="Enter some text" />
        <lightning:input name="input2" label="Text field with predefined value" value="initial value"/>
        <lightning:input name="input3" label="Text field with a placeholder" placeholder="type here..."/>
    </div>

    <div class="row">
        <h2 class="header">Advanced Input Text</h2>
        <lightning:input name="input4" readonly="true" value="initial value" label="Read-only text field with a predefined value" />
        <lightning:input name="input5" disabled="true" value="initial value" label="Disabled text field with a predefined value" />
        <lightning:input name="input6" required="true" value="0123456789" label="Required text field with a maximum length of 10" maxlength="10" />
        <lightning:input name="input7" label="Text field that handles the onfocus and onblur events" onfocus="{! c.handleFocus }" onblur="{! c.handleBlur }" />
    </div>

    <aura:attribute name="firstName" type="String"/>
    <div class="row">
        <h2 class="header">Live Input Text</h2>
        <lightning:input name="input8" value="{! v.firstName }" placeholder="type your first name..." label="Text field with attribute binding" />
        <p>
            FirstName: {! v.firstName }
        </p>
    </div>
</aura:component>
```

**What is being displayed on preview:**

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unlike in the flexi pages(Lightning app builder pages) when you use components in an app, Your app needs to extend `force:slds`.

[Using the Salesforce Lightning Design System in Apps](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.lightning.meta/lightning/apps_slds.htm)

The Salesforce Lightning Design System (SLDS) provides a look and feel that’s consistent with Lightning Experience. Use Lightning Design System styles to give your custom stand-alone Lightning applications a UI that is consistent with Salesforce, without having to reverse-engineer our styles.

Your application automatically gets Lightning Design System styles and design tokens if it extends force:slds. This method is the easiest way to stay up to date and consistent with Lightning Design System enhancements

```
<aura:application extends="force:slds">
    <!-- customize your application here -->
</aura:application>
```